# Pandas dataframe iloc with negation

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to set the value of the rows corresponding to a column to a specific value. I know only the indices of the rows which I should not set to that value. Is there an in-build trick to do this with iloc ?

is there something like

`df['I'].iloc[~rids] = 0`

Of course, one way to do this is to use something like

`set(range(len(df))).difference(rids)`

But it does not look very nice. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) of indexed real index values and [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'I' : ['A','B','C','D']}, index=list('abcd'))

indices = [0,3,1]

df.loc[df.index.difference(df.index[indices]), 'I'] = 0
```

Or with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.index[indices]), 'I'] = 0
```

Solution with positions and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is possible too:

```
df.iloc[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(df)), indices), df.columns.get_loc('I')] = 0
```

---

```
print (df)
   I
a  A
b  B
c  0
d  D
```